# I need to run a file that I placed on an AWS server using sftp

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, web, sftp, amazon-lightsail

I have a bitnami WordPress instance using AWS lightsail. I need to migrate the site to another identical AWS instance. I created a PHP installer from the first instance using the Wordpress Duplicator plugin.

I then uploaded the file onto the new server to a folder (opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/).The instructions I've seen online they say I just need to navigate to the location of the installer in a browser and it will run. However, when I attempt to access the PHP file from a browser I just get an error on the front-end saying:

```
OOPS! THAT PAGE CAN’T BE FOUND
```

I have seen suggestions online that the installer be placed into a public folder called html_public but my instance doesn't have a folder like that. I changed the access rights to the folder, and the installer, to be full rw access.

Any ideas how I can get this to work?

Comment: Check the ownership of the PHP file and ensure it's bitnami:bitnami

Comment: yes  bitnami bitnami is the Owner/Group for the files.

Comment: also, regardless of what I but in that folder, even a simple jpg, it gives the same error on the front end

Comment: I haven't used that particular plugin - but if you want to try a different one we go through a demo in this video that might be helpful:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ljJlxccq-xg&t=1334s

Comment: I had tried to use the All in One plug into but there is both a WordPress application and server side file size upload limit and my exported file is over 200Mb

Answer (score 0):

You must config the **Security Groups firewall** to open the **HTTP port**.

Open the **Amazon VPC console** at [https://console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/]

On the **Inbound Rules tab**, choose Edit the **port range 80, 443** - Source: Anywhere - **IP Address**: 0.0.0.0/0 and **Save**.